# Northern Ireland Roadway Network shapefile

Tags: shapefile, road, united-kingdom

Does anyone know of an open-source alternative to the £7k+ offering in the Ordinance Survey map shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the road network for Northern Ireland from Cloudmade in shp or osm format. Please check out http://downloads.cloudmade.com/europe/northern_europe/united_kingdom/northern_ireland#downloads_breadcrumbs

Comment: Happy it worked :)

Comment: This page no longer works. Anyone want to share it with me??